# Is "When to use which" Correct ?

Tags: expressions, usage

Let's assume we have n methods of doing X,
When i ask "When to use which ?" i expect the answer to be something like : "Use A when ... , Use B when ..."

By asking this question I want to ask "When to use each method"

I am sure i heard this expression before but I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"When to use which?" is incomplete.

"When should I use which?" is one of many possible complete versions of the question.

Comment: So it is correct when put into context ?  for exemple "I know there are many ways to do it but i want to know when to use which"

Comment: In that case your sentence is perfectly understandable. Personally I'd say "I know there are many ways to do it but I'd like to know when to use them", but your way is good too